# Question about Characteristic Polynomial and Invertible Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

I have a question as I prepare for my exam:

[image: question]

I want to use the Clayey-Hamilton theorem, because I know that every matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial.

The problem is I don't know how to represent that for a Linear Map.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is an invertible map, you can indeed find such a polynomial. The characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation $T$ is $p(\lambda) = \det(T - \lambda I)$, note that the notion of characteristic polynomial for a matrix comes from linear algebra itself, since matrices are just representations of linear maps. In this you would get $p(T) = 0$, the zero map in the space of linear maps on $V$, then if
$$p(T) = a_5 T^5 + a_4 T^4 + \cdots + a_0I = 0$$

Note that $a_0 \ne 0$, since $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $T$ (since $T$ is invertible). Multiplying the above by $T^{-1}$ (which is in fact, equivalent to composing the above map with $T^{-1}$), we get:
$$a_5 T^4 + \cdots + a_1 + a_0 T^{-1} = 0 \implies T^{-1} = -\frac{a_5}{a_0} T^4 - \cdots - \frac{a_1}{a_0}$$
Note that the order of multiplying $T^{-1}$ is irrelevant, since $T$ and $T^{-1}$ commute.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

== Let $\;P_T(x)=a)0+a_1x+\ldots+a_4x^4+x^4\;$ be the characteristic polynomial of $\;T\;$ , then$\;a_0\neq 0\;$

== We have that

$$a_0I +a_1T+\ldots+a_4T^4+T^5=0\implies a_0T^{-1}+a_1I+\ldots+a_4T^3+T^4=0\implies...$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $Q(X)=X^m+\ldots+a_1X+a_0$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. Since $T$ is invertible, the constant term $a_0$ is nonzero. Let $P(X)=\frac{Q(X)-a_0}{a_0X}=\frac1{a_0}X^{m-1}+\ldots +\frac{a_1}{a_0}$. Then $P(T)T=1$ as required.